# Unable to execute formula from Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am developing an application using `Apache POI` which executes a formula in Excel.

Basically I am dumping some data into Excel and then I try to execute a formula in Excel which throws the following `RuntimeException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected ptg class (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.ArrayPtg)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:663)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:505)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.TextFunction.evaluateIntArg(TextFunction.java:46)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.TextFunction$8.evaluate(TextFunction.java:210)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed3ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed3ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.LogicalFunction.evaluate(LogicalFunction.java:41)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed1ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getValue(AreaEvalBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.collectValues(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:151)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.getNumberArray(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.evaluate(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:90)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Match.eval(Match.java:95)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Match.evaluate(Match.java:85)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Var2or3ArgFunction.evaluate(Var2or3ArgFunction.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:205)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:374)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:202)
    at com.myt.ig.binary.ExcelWriter.readDecision(ExcelWriter.java:87)
    at com.myt.ig.binary.AbstractScanningThread.readDecision(AbstractScanningThread.java:27)
    at com.myt.ig.binary.Thread2Hr.run(Thread2Hr.java:41)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This is the formula I try to execute via `Apache POI`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(LaddersEpic,MATCH(TargetLadder,LaddersLong,FALSE),1)),INDEX(LaddersEpic,MATCH(TargetLadder,LaddersShort,FALSE),1),INDEX(LaddersEpic,MATCH(TargetLadder,LaddersLong,FALSE),1))
```

Comment: which apache-poi version is this?

Comment: apache poi version is 3.13

Comment: This formula is causing issue =MIN(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},K2),""))

Comment: Sounds equal to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366816/executing-a-formula-in-excel-via-apache-poi-throws-runtimeexception, unfortunately no solution there as well yet, sounds like the formula uses something that is not fully supported by POI, https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46989 sounds related